# AngularJs Checking for Session State Changes

Tags: angularjs, session, cookies

I'm trying to solve the issue of checking if a session has changed in angularJS.

I have multiple applications running on different tabs of a browser that share the same session. If a user is idle for too long on one tab of the application, I want to display an option for them to extend their session or to log out.

However, the user may not see that prompt since they may be busy using another application on another tab that shares a session with the application on the first tab. Logging out the user from the application on the first tab(the one the user was idle on) would log them out of the application of the second tab(which the user is actively using) since both tabs (although different applications) are sharing the same session.

How can I check the session cookie to see if it has changed on either tab?

Comment: The simplest solution is probably a timer checking the session regularly in every application

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution: http://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/

or

Try a timeout.

```
var myVar;

function mySessionCheckFunction() {
    // cancel the timeout
    if(myVar) 
         myStopFunction();

    // restart the timeout, after 15 min of idle show a popup confirm box
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ 
        var result =  window.confirm("Want to extend your session?"); 
        // result will be true or false
    }, 1000 * 60 * 15);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar); // clear the timeout
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onmousemove="mySessionCheckFunction()"> </body>
```